# Swift infinite loop in viewDidLoad

Tags: swift

I am having trouble figuring out what's going on in this simple app.  I created a basic Single View Application, added this function to the ViewController.swift:

```
func add() -> Double {
    var a = 0.0
    for var i = 0; i < 2; i++ {
        a = 1.0
    }
    return a
}
```

Here is my ViewController's viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var test = add()
}
```

If I put a breakpoint on the `return a` line, set it to continue after evaluating and print the breakpoint's hit count to the log then I can see that it just keeps going up and the view never loads.  What am I missing?

Comment: Looks good to me, try putting a breakpoint on this line "for var i = 0; i < 2; i++ {" and see what happens

Comment: I just moved my custom breakpoint to there and it only runs once, then I moved it inside the for loop and it ran twice. Then I realized that the view actually loaded both those times, so once I removed the breakpoint then everything runs fine... Is the breakpoint somehow causing the debugger to enter an endless loop there?  Is this a Xcode 6 beta 3 problem or am I using the breakpoint incorrectly?

Comment: First off let me explain why the breakpoint hit here twice. "for var i = 0; i < 2; i++ {" The first time it evaluates the condition to be true so it goes inside the loop. Then the second time it evaluates the condition to be false so leaves it leaves the loop. (That's standard programming behavior). Second point, yes you're probably using debugging incorrectly. You need to hit continue and exit debugging and the program should continue (if not you'll remain at the breakpoint hanging there). Try pressing step into, step out of, step over buttons, you'll figure it out.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I don't think you understand what I meant with the custom breakpoint. I understand how step into, step out of, etc works.  I created a breakpoint that automatically continues program execution after evaluation (no step in, out, etc).  In this case, my evaluation was simply "print to the console the number of times this breakpoint has been hit".  With the breakpoint, I have an endless loop.  Without the breakpoint, the program runs fine.  I think this is a bug in Xcode 6 beta 3.